# You can't specify target table 'location' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

For some reason I got the error in MySql: You can't specify target table 'location' for update in FROM clause

```
UPDATE location 
SET 
    lat = 37.05,
    lng = - 122.05,
    power = 90,
    speed = 90,
    utc = '155',
    gmt = '156'
WHERE
    location.index IN (SELECT 
            MAX(location.index)
        FROM
            location
        WHERE
            location.truckid = '1480c667-0bc9-3c60-85f3-6de3b6cd5ad4');
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put another `SELECT` around the subquery.

```
UPDATE location 
       SET lat = 37.05,
           lng = -122.05,
           power = 90,
           speed = 90,
           utc = '155',
           gmt = '156'
       WHERE index = (SELECT index
                             FROM (SELECT max(index) index
                                          FROM location
                                          WHERE location.truckid = '1480c667-0bc9-3c60-85f3-6de3b6cd5ad4') x);
```

Comment: There is a canonical answer for this error here on SO that provides explanation as well, not just a solution.

Comment: `UPDATE location 
       SET lat = 37.1,
           lng = -122.05,
           power = 90,
           speed = 90,
           utc = '155',
           gmt = '156'
       WHERE location.index = (SELECT *
                             FROM (SELECT max(location.index)
                                          FROM location
                                          WHERE location.truckid = '1480c667-0bc9-3c60-85f3-6de3b6cd5ad4') x);` the correct answer

Comment: @Duna: `SELECT *` without a `WHERE` in a scalar subquery certainly isn't the correct answer unless the table has only one column and a maximum of one row. At least the "only one" column condition can be ruled out as there are a more columns in the `SET` clause.